# Good floor material for multi-purpose indoor sports court

Tags: flooring, materials

We're building a new home and are considering a sports court that's large enough to play full-court pickleball. We want to be able to use the space for other activities as well, like basketball, soccer (maybe with matts for the goalie), gymnastics (definitely with matts), volleyball, and notably, roller-skating/skate boarding. I also would like one wall to have a ~5 foot ramp and platform that would be cool if it were the same material/part of the floor, but not necessarily.

I'm considering epoxy, but I'm concerned that would be too rough if one of the kids (or myself ) took a spill. I've thought of polished concrete, but I'm worried it may be too slippery. I've thought of polished wood, but I worry the maintenance would be a pain if I wanted to keep the skating from damaging it (if that were possible anyway).

I welcome suggestions and some prior experience/ideas of trade-offs that I should consider with regards to the material I use for the floor of my multi-purpose indoor sports court.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every multipurpose gym floor I've ever seen in a school (since that's about the only place I do see them) is maple (hardwood strips) with polyurethane finish. [The NBA apparently agrees](https://www.si.com/nba/2015/12/02/nba-hardwood-floors-basketball-court-celtics-nets-magic-nuggets-hornets), other than Boston.

Doesn't mean there are not schools where it's done otherwise, but the defacto standard for the Northeastern USA.

You're not a school, but it should inform your choice, perhaps...

Notably, that goes for traditional roller-skating rinks as well, though I suspect there are concrete ones out there (ouch.) Wheel material / durometer (hardness) is important for floor wear with skating.